# Save To-Many Relationships with Realm

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

the Problem is, that I can add relationships to my object and it works temporally but realm doesn't save the changes and when I quit the app and restart ist, the relationships are gone.

In the first view I create the main object. Here is the class:

```
class UserListClass: Object {
    dynamic var UserListName = ""
    let Medis = List<MediClass>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "UserListName"
    }
}
```

And the code how I create the object:

```
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let newList = UserListClass ()
            newList.UserListName = textField.text!
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(newList)
            }
```

This works without problems, and the object I add is also there when I restart the app.

When the user click on Edit it will open the next view:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showUserlistEdit" {
        let editViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MediUserlistEditViewController
        editViewController.userlist = userlist
    }

}
```

In the next view the code add selected entries to the list, I tried two versions, but both have the result, that it saves the relationships only for the runtime of the app. When I restart it, they are away.

First try:

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        userlist.Medis.append(medi)
        realm.add(userlist, update: true)
    }
```

Second try:

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        userlist.Medis.append(medi)
    }
```

Comment: Could you show please how you retrieve the `userlist` instance?  Are you sure that you operate on the same instance on the second run, as the one you created on the first run? Can you check the actual database contents with the browser and add screenshots? (https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the

```
let realm = try! Realm()
```

The documentation specify

```
// Get the default Realm
let realm = try! Realm()
// You only need to do this once (per thread)
```

You did on both view controllers and there is no guarantee that the path to the default Realm will be the same. It might work on the actual device but not on simulator.
Try this and delete all other occurrences

```
// Put this inside your Real class Definition/Declaration file
let realm = try! Realm()
```

Hope this help